# Interface for returning a collection in C++

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I have a class (or function) that takes a collection of objects, say points, and I need several different ways of creating them. Besides, I need to test the class that takes them, so I've thought of creating an interface or base class for the "point collection creator" classes.

I know the idiomatic way of accepting a collection of objects into a function in C++ is to pass two templated iterators. Something like this:

```
template <typename Iterator>
double doSomething(Iterator first, Iterator last);
```

But how about returning a collection? How to declare a set of classes that return a collection so I can pass it to such a function?

Should I just return the collection (vector or whatever), then get its begin and end iterators to pass them? Or should I mimick a container's interface? (This could be useful later to test the concrete classes and use Google Mock's ASSERT_THAT with ElementsAre, for example).

---

**UPDATE. I'm adding a little more info**

As I said, I need to process some points. For simplicity's sake, let's say I need to take a series of points, do some calculations on them, and return a value (e.g. mean distance between consecutive points):

```
double ProcessPoints(/*Take points somehow*/);
```

Or maybe:

```
class PointProcessor
{
public:
    PointProcessor(/*Take points somehow*/);
    double Run();
//...
}
```

Now, I need several ways to create the series of points, e.g. a series of N random points, the intersection points of a series of line segments, a fake for tests... So I thought they should have a common interface or base class:

```
class PointsGenerator { /*...*/ };

class RandomPoints : public PointsGenerator{ /*...*/ };
class IntersectionsBetweenSegments : public PointsGenerator{ /*...*/ };
class FakePointsGenerator : public PointsGenerator{ /*...*/ };
//...
```

So should PointsGenerator just return a vector, should it provide begin and end functions as if it were a container, none of those options...? Maybe I'm doing it all wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use this entire interface, from creating the container to passing it to another function?

Comment: Return iterators with functions `begin` and `end` (like all of standard containers do)

Comment: And what you want to do with that collection inside doSomething function? Cause if you want for example fill it (using push_back method etc.), then template isn't good aproach, you need some generic interface, that will be inherited by all collections, so you can use polymorphism and call same method on different objects(method for inserting on collections)

Comment: @sftrabbit The thing is I'm not really sure even how I want to do it. I'll edit the question to try to add more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  There are two situations:

- You're constructing a new container.  This is somewhat like
  a factory method; in this case, you return the container.
- You're returning a reference to an existing container.  In
  this case, you can either return a reference to the container,
  or provide two functions, one which returns the `begin`
  iterator, and another which returns the `end` iterator.

From what you describe, you're in the first case.  You really
have no alternative: if you want to create an object, it has to
live somewhere, and it can't live in the function which creates
it.

One could argue that the design of the library containers is
such that you shouldn't be using factory functions.  (Factory
functions are mainly for dynamically allocated, polymorphic
objects.  You almost never want to allocate a container
dynamically, and the standard containers are not polymorphic.)
If you have the sequence which should be used to initialize the
container, you can treat it as the second case, above, and write
somthing like:

```
std::vector<Whatever> v( beginWhatever(), endWhatever() );
```

In other words, leave the creation of the actual container to
the client, and just provide him with the initialization
sequence.

Comment: For completeness, there is also the option to pass a reference to an existing container.